# How to load a view in codeigniter where multiple forms are used

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view:

```
<form action="HomeController.php" method="post">
    Available Batches:<select name="batch">
    <?php  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('login');
    $sql = "SELECT b_id FROM batch where type='C#'and seats_left!=0";
    $result=  mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <option value="" ><?php echo $row["b_id"];?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="new" value="new"><br>
</form>

<?php echo form_open('HomeController/Enteringdata') ?>
Enter batch id:<input type="text" name="b"><br>
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="enter"><br>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function Enteringdata() {
    if($this->input->post('enter')=="enter"){
        $b= $this->input->post('b');
        $this->load->Model('LoginModel');
        $seats=$this->LoginModel->batch($b);
        $seats--;
        $this->LoginModel->ins($seats,$b);
    }
    elseif($this->input->post('new')=="new")
    {
        $this->load->view('batchc'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add this syntax `<?php $this->load->view('your view name');  ?>` inside your view.

Comment: What are you even doing? Connecting to MySQL in your view? Please go read up on the basics of the MVC concept. This is nightmare-ish.

Comment: I have solved it. My second submit button was outside the first form. Thanks for your help anyway and yes you need to connect to database when using script and pull data from database. It's not nightmare-ish. Maybe you need to do more coding than reading about MVC concept.